# Finding out Energy value

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, potential, field-theory, non-linear-systems

A Lagrangian is given by,
$$L= \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2 R^d \left[\frac{1}{2}\dot A^2 - V(A_{max})\right]$$
$$E=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2R^d V(A_{max}) $$
where V (A) now includes nonlinear terms and E is the energy which is found by taking the appropriate Legendre transform of the Lagrangian and evaluating it at the upper turning point of an oscillation, $A_{max}$.
Now using the potential $V= \phi^2-\phi^3+\frac{\phi^4}{4}$, and $\phi=A(t)e^\frac{-r^2}{R^2}$we can write, 
$$V(A)= (1+\frac{d}{2R^2})A^2-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^\frac{d}{2} A^3+ \frac{A^4}{2^\frac{d+4}{2}}$$ 
$$V''(A)= (2+\frac{d}{R^2})-6\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^\frac{d}{2} A+ 3\frac{A^2}{2^\frac{d}{2}}$$

> For $d=2$, they got $E_{\infty}=4.44$ and $d=3$ they found the value $E_{\infty}=39.69$, but how? **Why do we write here $E_{\infty}$?** For more information [please check equations 13 and 14 in the link](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of $E_{\infty}$ were probably calculated numerically. They explain in the paper that they rewrote the equation for the energy to contain only $A$. So what will have done is input a range of realistic values for $A$ and plot the energy in that range. They found a minimum and calculated the value of $E$ in that minimum (that's not too hard).

The reason for writing $E_{\infty}$ will be because there is apparently an [attractor point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor) in configuration space to which the oscillon tends. This means that *after a long time* the oscillon will come infinitesimally close to that point. It will 'settle down' there. The energy corresponding to that point is therefore a good approximation for the energy after a long time ($t\rightarrow\infty$). That's most likely why this energy is subscripted with an infinity symbol.

Comment: Can you elaborate that how did they get $E_\infty$?

Comment: Well, so they got an equation for $E$ in terms of $A$ alone, making it possible for them to calculate any $E$ corresponding to some $A$ (at a fixed $d$). They most likely used an algorithm to scan a physically relevant range of $A$'s, trying to determine for which $A$ the energy was minimal. (have a look at their figure 2, they basically searched for the minimum of that curve numerically) This minimal energy then is $E_{\infty}$.

Comment: Is the figure representing equation(11), if so then what would be the value or radius and the potential?  Can you represents that numerically  please(IF possible)?

Comment: The figure is indeed representing equation (11), but the radius and potential were substituted. Equation (14) was used to get an expression for $R$ by setting that equation equal to $0$. Then the obtained expression for $R$ was substituted into equation (11) and equation (13). Lastly, this adjusted equation (13) was used for the potential in equation (11). So by this procedure they got an expression $E(A)$ for the energy, only depending on $A$. This explanation is roughly present in the paper as well, under equation (14).

Comment: Got it, but are they using $V(A_{max})$ in equation  because V''=0 ?
If this is true then why they wrote( below the figure 2) $V(A_{max})$=$V(A_{min})$?

Comment: The equation $V(A_{min})=V(A_{max})$ simply expresses inversion symmetry of the potential. You can sort of compare it to a spring if that helps. The potential for that case is $kx^2/2$ where $x$ is the displacement from $x=0$. The highest amplitude is then $x=+A$, the smallest one $x=-A$. The potential is obviously the same for both. I haven't read through the entire paper, but I assume they use $V(A_{max})$ because at $A_{max}$ there is no kinetic energy and so it all comes down to the potential energy, governed by $V(A)$. $V''=0$ is just a (valid) way of getting an equation for $R(A)$.

Comment: Why this is a *valid* way is justified in the first few sentences of section `C. The Attractor Point`.

Comment: I have done as you said my mathematica but I didmn't get as author got ,
here is the code: 
Plot[(27 6^(3/4) (-(2/3) Sqrt[2/3] A^3 + A^4/(8 Sqrt[2]) +A^2 (1 + (-12 Sqrt[6] + 48 A - 9 Sqrt[3] A^2)/( 12 Sqrt[6]))) \[Pi]^(3/2))/(-12 Sqrt[6] + 48 A - 9 Sqrt[3] A^2)^(3/2), {A, 0.5, 2.5}]

Comment: I don't own a copy of Mathematica, but I've ran some code with Matlab and I also couldn't replicate their results. So I took a closer look at the maths in their paper and it looks OK, until equation (13). There's one term in there which I cannot account for, namely the one with $d/(2R^2)$. This is the crucial term, since it allows them to rewrite equation (11) solely in terms of $A$, but it seems (to me at least) this term shouldn't actually be there. Now I'm wondering if I've done the maths wrong, though I doubt it since I do get the other terms...

Comment: If you happen to see where they got that term, I'd be interested in hearing it (it could of course still be that it's something very plain and I'm just staring it in the face and missing it). If not, perhaps you want to ask a new question about that as well. And if you don't, I actually might :)